# AWS Lex with Lambda integration using CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, amazon-lex

I am trying to connect Lex with Lambda using CDK (TS).

I am getting `Invalid Bot Configuration: Access denied while invoking lambda function arn:aws:lambda:xyz from arn:aws:lex:zyx. Please check the policy on this function`

I have tried applying inline policies using AWS Console.
But nothing works.
I was trying to attach * policies - not working either.

My code looks something like this:

```js
    const botRole = new Role(this, 'bot-role', {
      assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lex.amazonaws.com'),
      inlinePolicies: {
        'allow-everything': new PolicyDocument({
          statements: [
            new PolicyStatement({
              effect: Effect.ALLOW,
              resources: ['*'],
              actions: ['*'],
            }),
          ],
        }),
      },
    });

    const botLambdaHandler = new NodejsFunction(
      this,
      'bot-lambda-handle',
      {
        entry: join(__dirname, 'resources', 'bot-handler.ts'),
        ...nodeJsFunctionProps,
        role: new Role(this, 'bot-execution-role', {
          assumedBy: new ServicePrincipal('lambda.amazonaws.com'),
          inlinePolicies: {
            'allow-everything': new PolicyDocument({
              statements: [
                new PolicyStatement({
                  effect: Effect.ALLOW,
                  resources: ['*'],
                  actions: ['*'],
                }),
              ],
            }),
          },
        }),
      }
    );

    const bot = new CfnBot(this, 'bot-name', {
      name: 'bot-name',
      roleArn: role.roleArn,
      ...
      { testAliasConfig with arn of botLambdaHandler }
    });


   const botVersion = new CfnBotVersion(this, 'bot-prod-version', {
      botId: bot.attrId,
      botVersionLocaleSpecification: [
        {
          localeId: 'en_US',
          botVersionLocaleDetails: {
            sourceBotVersion: 'DRAFT',
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    new CfnBotAlias(this, 'bot-prod-alias', {
      botAliasName: 'BotProd',
      botId: bot.attrId,
      botVersion: botVersion.attrBotVersion,
      botAliasTags: tags,
      botAliasLocaleSettings: [
        {
          localeId: 'en_US',
          botAliasLocaleSetting: {
            enabled: true,
            codeHookSpecification: {
              lambdaCodeHook: {
                codeHookInterfaceVersion: '1.0',
                lambdaArn: botLambdaHandler.functionArn,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });
```

I have tried applying inline policies using AWS Console. Nothing works :(
I will be glad for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Lambda function’s [resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html) isn't allowing AWS Lex to invoke it, hence the 'access denied while *invoking* lambda function' error.

After you've fixed all of the dangerous allow all policies (please!), use [`addPermission(...)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.Permission.html) to modify the policy to allow the bot to invoke your Lambda:

```js
botLambdaHandler.addPermission('lex-fulfillment', {
      action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction',
      principal: new iam.ServicePrincipal('lex.amazonaws.com'),
});
```

Note that for v2 Lex bots, the service principal is `lexv2.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: I would like to THANK YOU VERY MUCH <3
I have removed dangerous policies. I have added them only as last resort.
You are the boss :)

Comment: Also - the AWS documentation should emphasize lexv2.amazonaws.com principal.
I was using v1 one. Because of that hasn't been working.